# Joomla: Publish and Unpublish pages automatically?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

Is there anyway to publish and unpublish pages automatically in certain time in Joomla or any other CMS? If so how?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. 
In Joomla, in the article itself, there is a section about publishing, where you can set INITIAL DATE of PUBLISHING and END DATE.  By default, the INITIAL date is the moment you created and published by the first time the article... and the END DATE is set to "NEVER".

You need to edit your article to access this publishing section.